# Evaluating trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to build image classification network (2 classes, cats and non cats). NN is defined like this:

```
def construct_network(X, params):
   Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(params["W1"], X), params["b1"])
   A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)

   Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(params["W2"], A1), params["b2"])
   A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)

   Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(params["W3"], A2), params["b3"])
   return Z3
```

Cost function:

```
def calc_cost(Z3, Y):
   logits = tf.transpose(Z3)
   labels = tf.transpose(Y)
   return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
```

And then:

```
Z3 = construct_network(X_p, params)
cost = calc_cost(Z3, Y_p)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

And typical result looks like this:

```
Cost for epoch 0: 49.456378
Cost for epoch 100: 12.760913
Cost for epoch 200: 10.387191
Cost for epoch 300: 13.810563
Cost for epoch 400: 9.316090
Cost for epoch 500: 8.210016
Cost for epoch 600: 7.901745
Cost for epoch 700: 8.416944
Cost for epoch 800: 5.621855
Cost for epoch 900: 5.904790
Cost for epoch 1000: 4.743062
Cost for epoch 1100: 8.970100
Cost for epoch 1200: 6.074375
Cost for epoch 1300: 12.980518
Cost for epoch 1400: 6.193832
```

[image]

I've tried using trained model like this:

```
 (files, X, Y) = generate_minibatch(test_samples)

result = sess.run(Y_predict, feed_dict={X_p: X})
# result = Y_predict.eval(feed_dict={X_p: X})

result = (tf.argmax(result, 0)).eval()
actual_result = tf.argmax(Y, 0).eval()
difference = tf.equal(result, actual_result).eval()
```

But actual result seems to be just random. Sometimes it guesses some images correctly. Sometimes it outputs the same values for all test samples.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I using trained model correctly?
2. If yes then I have some issues in the learning part. How can I tell if the network is being learnt correctly?
3. What could be causing this cost function fluctuations?
4. What could be causing cost function not changing from epoch to epoch? This also happened but after a loot of changes I haven't
   figured what actually helped.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually on some other training set final cost value was much lover. But fluctuations were still present..

Comment: Fluctuations should always be there, since this is non-convex problem. If you modify the network to be a single layer, you will see a much smoother loss.

Comment: In the training part, can you print the accuracy along with the loss?. That will tell you whether the network is learning. Also do the same thing for a validation set during training.

Comment: In my case how do I calculate accuracy? Something like correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(result, 1), tf.argmax(actual_result, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))